# Quick Way to Update iOS requirement in app store?

Tags: ios5, app-store

My app was approved yesterday and is now available in the app store. I just realized that my app is not compatible with iOS 5.0 due to an NSLayout exception. Is there a way that I can quickly update the iOS requirement to 6.0? Or do I have to do this through an app update?

Time is of the essence and I don't want anyone with iOS 5.0 downloading my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem easily by unchecking autolayout in all of my xibs. Hopefully Apple approves my update soon!